# Sum every column for all rows?

Tags: angular

I have this:

```
 <tr table-tr *ngFor="let key of Object.keys(channels); let i=index" [data]="data" [channels]="channels"
            [width]="width" [name]="key" [i]="i" [mainObj]="obj" (emitter)="emitter($event)"></tr>
          <tr>
```

Table-tr component:

**{{name | translate}}**

Table-tds component:

```
<table-td [data]="data" [field]="field" [total]="total"></table-td>
```

Table-td component:

```
<input class='input' (focusout)="sumTotal()" type="number" step="0.01" [(ngModel)]="field.value">
```

I want to sum all data for every column each but to be honest i dont have any ide how to do that?
I dont have all data for every row that i can foreach all rows and sum for example index(0).

Any suggestion how can i achive this?

Comment: Can you share it in stackbiltz

Comment: Just wondering, if you do not have data for every row then how you will get the total. I suggest to edit and provide more clear information.

Answer (score 0):

> dont have all data for every row that i can foreach all rows and sum
>   for example index(0)

If you don't have data then you cannot get total for it. I would use the following if I am displaying data in the table and need total for each column.

Create a method and call for each column to have total of it in the HTML Markup:

```
getTotal(col) {
  return this.data.map(d => d[col]).reduce((colValue, value) => colValue + value, 0);
}
```

And in the HTML:

```
getTotal('nameOfColumn');
```

Comment: i dont mean i dont have data its just i cannot access that that for every column on parent column because of structure